# Is there a way I can output multiple ranges of values based on a condition in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I am currently working on a problem where I am trying to find the range of times when something "important" is happening in my dataset. This importance comes from two objects being close to each other, so I was thinking I would just subset my dataframe to when the objects fall within a certain range of each other. For example, if my dataframe was like this, and I wanted the moments where my objects were within 1000-2000 of each other,

```
    Timestamp   Dist from Each Other
0   1s              1000
0   2s              2000
0   3s              3000
0   4s              2000
0   5s              1000
```

Then I would desire an output, that gives me the answer of the objects being that close between 1-2 seconds, and 4-5 seconds. Instead, right now, I am just getting an output of 1-5 seconds because my function does not know when it leaves that range and comes back in.

Anyone know anything I can do? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I set up the following test data frame.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'t': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'd': [1000, 2000, 3000, 2000, 1000]})
>>> df['last'] = df['d'].shift(1)
   t     d    last  enter  exit
0  1  1000     0.0      1     0
1  2  2000  1000.0      1     1
2  3  3000  2000.0      1     1
3  4  2000  3000.0      2     1
4  5  1000  2000.0      2     2
```

I create indicator variables for the starts and ends of different groups. To do that, I need first to compare the value `d` with the value before it, which I call `last` (supra).

Because I want the group IDs to be distinct, I use a cumulative sum to force a serial count. For the `exit` variable, because your intervals are inclusive, I shift them backwards.

```
>>> df['enter'] = df.eval('1000 <= d <= 2000 and not (1000 <= last <= 2000)').cumsum()
>>> df['exit'] = df.eval('1000 <= last <= 2000 and not (1000 <= d <= 2000)') \
        .shift(-1).fillna(True).cumsum()
```

I merge the frame on a subset of itself (on `entrance` and `exit`) such that each interval gains an end time. Dropping duplicates in the `enter` variable, which uniquely identifies the interval series, recovers the actual intervals.

```
>>> temp = df.merge(df.drop_duplicates('exit', keep='first')[['t', 'exit']],  
                    left_on='enter', right_on='exit', how='left', suffixes=['', '_end'])
   t     d    last  enter  exit  t_end  exit_end
0  1  1000     0.0      1     0      2         1
1  2  2000  1000.0      1     1      2         1
2  3  3000  2000.0      1     1      2         1
3  4  2000  3000.0      2     1      5         2
4  5  1000  2000.0      2     2      5         2

>>> temp.drop_duplicates(subset='enter', keep='first')[['t', 't_end']]
   t  t_end
0  1      2
3  4      5
```

Comment: This looks great, thank you so much! I will try it out and let you know how it goes!

Answer (score -1):

I'm unsure if I understand your question fully.

It looks like a simple filter

df = df[(df["Dist from each other"]>=1000) & (df["Dist from each other"]<=2000)]

Are your timestamps actual timestamps or time durations?
1s = 1st second or 1 second during which distance was 1000m apart
4s = 4th second or 4 seconds duration during which distance was 1000m apart?

If it is durations, then after the filtration, a histogram of timestamps should do.

If it is actual timestamps, the first step filtration is still the answer. But I'm not sure if that's sufficient for you.